# How to get the id of a form in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to develop a page in Django where there is multiple form that the user can modify.

For this, I need to get the id of the form the user ask to modify.

There is my code:

models.py:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    date = models.DateField()
```

forms.py:

```
class OrderForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model = Order
         fields = ["date"]
```

views.py:

```
def order(request, identifiant):
    user_orders = []
    form_user_orders = []
    user = User.objects.get(username=identifiant) #We use identifiant from the url to get the user
    user_orders.append(Order.objects.filter(user=user.id)) #We get all order of the user
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            order_instance = Order(
                id = None, #This is where I have a problem
                user=User(id=user.id),
                date=form.cleaned_data["date"],
            )
            order_instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(f"/forms/orders/{identifiant}")
    else:
        for order in user_orders[0]: #We iterate on all orders and put them in another list as form instances
            form_user_orders.append(OrderForm(instance=order))
    return render(request, "forms/orders.html", {"identifiant": identifiant, "forms": form_user_orders})
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("orders/<identifiant>", views.order)
]
```

order.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <title>Order</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% for form in forms %}
            <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div>
                    <label>Date</label>
                    <div>
                        {{ form.date }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the `identifiant` here?

Comment: Have you tried on using Formsets?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The identifiant is the username. It is specified in the url and is used to know what order is assigned to the user.

Comment: @Titouan: but you know the logged in user with `request.user`, by adding an `identifiant` to the URL, someone can spoof the system and thus make an order for another person.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes I know. The website is very far from finish but I assumed I will use this system to simulate a connected user. It should kinda work the same way no ? (excepted for the security issue)

Comment: @Titouan: well you will need to pass the order(id) to use. This can be done through the URL, a POST parameter (hidden input element), etc. But the form thus needs to keep track for what item it is editing

Comment: @CzarLuc So I took a moment today to study formset but it doesn't seem to fix my problem

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem This is what i tried in the first place but its not working. I tried to send a dict through the render but in this case the form dont work. I also tried to put id with date in my forms file but Django dont let me do it.